# How can I return an install error back to the Module Manager in Prestashop 1.7?

Tags: php, module, prestashop-1.7

I am trying to debug my Module installation where a few times it will return false based on certain fields. Depending on which fails, I want to display an output. I have tried:

```
\Tools::displayError('This worked.');
array_push($this->context->controller->errors, $this->l('This worked.'));
```

My install looks like this:

```
public function install() {
    \Tools::displayError('This worked.');
    array_push($this->context->controller->errors, $this->l('This worked.'));
    return (parent::install() && false); // Force a fail to test
}
```

However, all I seem to get is:

```
Unfortunately, the module did not return additional details.
```

I have looked on the internet for fixes but [have only come across outdated ones](https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/162677-standard-method-for-modules-to-pass-errorwarnings-back-to-the-module-manager/). Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: my constructor has need_instance set to 1:

```
public function __construct() {
    ...
    $this->need_instance = 1;
    ...
    parent::__construct();
    ...
}
```

Update: To help future viewers, the `insert` function of the `Db` class automatically adds the prefix to the table name. Removing the `self::DB_PREFIX` fixed this issue.

```
return \Db::getInstance()->insert('iezon_portfolio', array(
    'img_link' => pSQL($img),
    'title' => pSQL($title),
    'description' => pSQL($description),
    'company_name' => pSQL($company),
    'company_url' => pSQL($company_url),
    'testimonial' => pSQL($testimonial),
    'is_favourite' => (int) $fav,
));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
public function install()
{
    if ($this->checkForErrors()) {
        $this->_errors[] = $this->l('Error message');
        return false;
    }

    ...rest of the code...
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I had no clue you could output errors using the `_errors` property. I used `\Db::getInstance()->getMsgError()` and the `self::DB_PREFIX` was outputting twice. Seems that there is some auto prefix addition in the `insert()` method for the table name. Removing this fixed the issue.

Comment: yep, there is an option to force `insert` method to ommit prefix but it's rarely used :)

Comment: Are you quite familiar with Prestashop development? This is the first time really using it and just displaying a god damn page is beyond effort and why they've made it this way is beyond me... currently trying to extend a `ModuleFrontController`, setting the template is easy but its blank... trying to add the header and footer is proving a tedious task and the documentation is beyond useless

Comment: Because of template inheritance you need to extend some base file, for example page.tpl, take a look here:

https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/themes/reference/template-inheritance/

Comment: Perhaps you could take a [look at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63377855/how-can-i-display-the-header-and-footer-in-a-modulefrontcontroller-in-prestashop) I just asked on this subject. I read through them docs but they reference nothing about getting the layout when using a `ModuleFrontController` - thanks in advance man!